# Change buffer size in VFS

Tags: java, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

I am using [VFS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) for the file operation.
While IO operation one the below method comes in the flow.

class `DefaultFileContent`

method `public long write(final OutputStream output, final int bufferSize) throws IOException`
[javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/commons-vfs2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/DefaultFileContent.html)

[source code](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/commons-vfs2/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/DefaultFileContent.html#line.797)
which writes output stream from input stream and It uses BUFFER SIZE of 4096.

I want to increase this buffer size I have an idea for re-compiling the source.
But is there any configuration for the same?